# Drupal 8 render custom theme from custom module

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

This used to work for me without fail when Drupal 8 first came out.  However this does not seem to work anymore and I get an error.  Drupal docs have always been horrid so no solution there.

**custom.module**

```
<?php

function custom_theme() {
    $theme['home_page'] = [
        'variables' => ['name' => NULL],
        'template' => 'home_page'
    ];

    return $theme;
}

function custom_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/config/system/custom'] = array(
    'title' => 'Custom',
    'description' => 'Configuration Custom',
    'route_name' => 'custom.settings'
  );
  return $items;
}
```

**custom.routing.yml**

```
custom.home:
    path: /home
    defaults: 
        _controller: Drupal\custom\Controller\RoutingController::home
    requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
```

**src/Controller/RoutingController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom\Controller;

class RoutingController {
    public function home(){
        return array(
            '#title' => 'Home',
            '#theme' => 'home_page'
        );
    }

}
```

**home_page.html.twig**

```
<main>
   <!-- some markup -->
</main>
```

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2017-05-15/drupal-8-custom-module-template#comment-12166287 a helpful link for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your controller not extending the base controller class problem one
try this

```
namespace Drupal\custom\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class RoutingController extends ControllerBase{
    public function home(){
        return array(
            '#title' => 'Home',
            '#theme' => 'home_page'
        );
    }

}
```

**home_page.html.twig**

```
<main>
   <!-- some markup -->
   {{ content }}
</main>
```

also try to extend you theme hook with path

```
'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'custom') . '/templates',
```

and place your template twig file in your module/templates folder